# populating AJAX javascript/jQuery dropdown (province, state, city) gives undefined ocassionaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I am currently using jquery-1.11.1.min.js. I have three different dropdowns, province, state, city and I have the following javascript to handle changes when a user has selected a province, state, or city.

```
$provinceSelector = $('.selector-province');
$stateSelector = $('.selector-state');
$citySelector = $('.selector-city');

$provinceSelector.on('change', function () {
        var provinceid = $(this).val();
        $stateSelector.html('<option value>Loading...</option>');
        $stateSelector.attr('disabled','true');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/location/states/' + provinceid,
            timeout: 20000,
            type: 'GET',
            data: [],
            success: function (response) {
                if (!response.status || response.states.length == 0)
                {
                    $provinceSelector.val('');
                    $stateSelector.html('<option value>Pilih kabupaten lokasi toko kamu</option>');
                }
                else if (response.status && response.states.length > 0 && $stateSelector)
                {
                    $stateSelector.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $stateSelector.html('<option value>Pilih kabupaten</option>');
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.states.length; i++)
                    {
                        $stateSelector.append('<option value="' + response.states[i].id + '">' + response.states[i].name + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (x, t, m) {
                $provinceSelector.val('');
                $stateSelector.html('<option value>Pilih kabupaten lokasi toko kamu</option>');
            },
        });
    });
```

The end point that the server returns looks like this:

```
{"status":true,"cities":[{"id":67,"name":"Alas"},{"id":68,"name":"Alas Barat"},{"id":472,"name":"Batu Lanteh"},{"id":1233,"name":"Empang"},{"id":2276,"name":"Labangka"},{"id":2283,"name":"Labuhan Badas"},{"id":2338,"name":"Lape-Lopok"},{"id":2547,"name":"Lunyuk"},{"id":2919,"name":"Moyohilir"},{"id":2920,"name":"Moyohulu"},{"id":3605,"name":"Plampang"},{"id":3936,"name":"Ropang"},{"id":4603,"name":"Sumbawa"},{"id":4604,"name":"Sumbawa Besar"},{"id":5265,"name":"Utan-Rhee"}]}
```

it can also return status false if something wrong happens. Now the issue is that on several occasions I am getting reports from user where they are seeing `undefined` in the state after selecting a province (in other words there are no options in state, just undefined),  this usually is on a mobile device. I wonder how this is even possible? I think I am handling every single possible case there is. Any ideas/hints?

Comment: If province undefined you can not show it. But may be I'm not underastand your question completely

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that could cause this. It must be undefined in the response.

Comment: @AlexFilatov it just happened sometimes and not all the time and it's for certain devices as well

Comment: you should add validation on 'undefined' what variables you expect can come in response equal undefined

Comment: @AlexFilatov how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before - check/validate for undefined (if/try catch...) and make some logging on server to see what is happening :)

And another hint - mobile can have bad coverage / timeout / etc. - that's why you probably set 20s timeout. That would be my next step i debugging.

Comment: you mean try catch in javascript? can you show some code?

Comment: Ok, if undefined is ment in such context - then Alex-es example below is ok. Still - in such cases some server side logging will quickly show the problem... So end user only reports approximate time of "error" and you check logs and act on them...

Answer (score 0):

In your case it can be happens because from any issues:

1. Long ping from server. (so why you using 20s timeout).
2. Issues in js library on mobile devices.

Fix of this issue can be like set validation `if (response.states[i] != undefined )` or use `try catch` construction. Below I've provide some code which will be execute without `undefined` errors.

```
$provinceSelector = $('.selector-province');
$stateSelector = $('.selector-state');
$citySelector = $('.selector-city');

$provinceSelector.on('change', function () {
        var provinceid = $(this).val();
        $stateSelector.html('<option value>Loading...</option>');
        $stateSelector.attr('disabled','true');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/location/states/' + provinceid,
            timeout: 20000,
            type: 'GET',
            data: [],
            success: function (response) {
                if (!response.status || response.states.length == 0)
                {
                    $provinceSelector.val('');
                    $stateSelector.html('<option value>Pilih kabupaten lokasi toko kamu</option>');
                }
                else if (response.status && response.states.length > 0 && $stateSelector)
                {
                    $stateSelector.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $stateSelector.html('<option value>Pilih kabupaten</option>');
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.states.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (response.states[i] != undefined ) {   // here you can add validate expression
                           $stateSelector.append('<option value="' + response.states[i].id + '">' + response.states[i].name + '</option>');
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (x, t, m) {
                $provinceSelector.val('');
                $stateSelector.html('<option value>Pilih kabupaten lokasi toko kamu</option>');
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: I added more clarification in the original question about what undefined means